# I have a matrix 12*4, and I need to subtract the 3rd column elements of rows that are different

Tags: matlab

I have a 12x4 matrix in MATLAB,

```
A =[-1,    3,   152,    41.5 ;
     3,    9,   152,    38.7 ;
     9,   16,   152,    38.7 ;
    16,   23,   129,    53.5 ;
    23,   29,   129,    53.5 ;
    29,   30,   100,   100   ;
    30,   30.5, 83,     83   ;
    30.5, 31,   83,     83   ;
    31,   35,   83,     83   ;
    35,   41,   129,    53.5 ;
    41,   48,   129,    53.5 ;
    48,   55,   152,    38.7 ] ;
```

and I need to find the changes in the rows by subtracting the 3rd column element of the 2nd row from the previous row 3rd column element if they are different else go to the 3rd row if the same.

The answer should be in the form:

```
  B = [16, 23;
       29, 29;
       30, 17;
       35, 46;
       48, 23]
```

For example, the 3rd and the 4th row 3rd column elements are different, so if subtracted i got 23. Output B 1st column element will consist of the 4th row first column element.

Comment: This question is of no interested to SO and will be downvoted by others.

Comment: Please format your question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

```
%Given matrix
A =[-1,     3,   152,    41.5 ;
     3,     9,   152,    38.7 ;
     9,    16,   152,    38.7 ;
    16,    23,   129,    53.5 ;
    23,    29,   129,    53.5 ;
    29,    30,   100,   100   ;
    30,    30.5,  83,    83   ;
    30.5,  31,    83,    83   ;
    31,    35,    83,    83   ;
    35,    41,   129,    53.5 ;
    41,    48,   129,    53.5 ;
    48,    55,   152,    38.7 ] ;

B=A(:,2:3);    %Taking out the columns of our interest
B = B([diff(B(:,2))~=0; true],:);   %Storing only those rows whose consecutive elements in the third column of A are different
B=[B(1:end-1,1) abs(diff(B(:,2)))] % First column is according to your condition and second column is the difference
```

Comment: Hahahah. Well done @Sardar_Usama for teaching young whippersnappers elegant code *and* proper etiquette! :p